# jQuery method to select a subset and also its inverse?

Tags: jquery

Given some jQuery object set, and also a subset of that set, is there a method that will return the **inverse** subset?

If the answer is "**No**", is there any way to avoid making a *second selection* to get the inverse subset?

**Explanatory example:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="subset"></li>
  <li class="subset"></li>
  <li class="inverse"></li>
  <li class="inverse"></li>
</ul>
```

First I want to do something to all the `<li>`, then something to only `.subset`, and finally something else to only `.inverse`:

```
$('li').css('background-color','blue')
  .filter('.subset')
    .css('color','black')
  .inverse()  // <-- White Whale?!?
    .css('color','white');
```

I know this could be easily done with `.end().filter('.inverse')`, but suppose the selector were actually **big** and **nasty** and running it twice would be a big **performance hit**.  What then?

Haven't found anything like this in the API docs, but I'm new to jQuery and may have overlooked something obvious (also, the existence of `.andSelf()` means this would not be unreasonable to expect...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built-in function for this, the reverse filter is what you're after...the alternative isn't chainable.  The alternative would be [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/), like this:

```
var all = $('li').css('background-color','blue');
var sub = all.filter('.subset').css('color','black');
all.not(sub).css('color','white');
```

...but again it's not pretty, I'd stick with the `.end().filter()` approach.  However, if performance is paramount, use the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) approach above, it is more efficient (since no selector runs for the inverse set).

---

For your specific example (though not the general question), it'd be pretty quick to do this:

```
$('li').css('background-color','blue').css('color','white')
       .filter('.subset').css('color','black');
```

Comment: Great.  Thanks for discussing all the options.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little extension to jquery about it that i just made..

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.reverse = function () 
  {
      var orig = this.prevObject || jQuery(null);
      return orig.not(this);
  }
})(jQuery);
```

It will maintain the chaining, so you can still do `.end()` after it and return to the previous filtering.

You can call it like

```
$('li').css('background-color','blue')
  .filter('.subset')
    .css('color','black')
  .reverse()  // <-- White Whale?!?
    .css('color','white');
```

**Demo** with your example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/THLkn/

Comment: +1, very cool! I Hadn't realized that extensions were so straightforward.