# jquery select elements from a given selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery method to select a subset and also its inverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502533/jquery-method-to-select-a-subset-and-also-its-inverse)

given this javascript code

```
var radio_buttons = $('.search-options input[type="radio"]');
```

I want to get only the checked radio button from the collection of radio buttons that the variable holds. I thought that the find method could help achieving that, but it doesn't.

```
radio_buttons.find('input[checked]')
```

Any other way to do it?

Comment: All of you have posted the same answer, Hope the person who asked will be confused which one to choose as selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method and [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector:

```
radio_buttons.filter(":checked"). ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)** to select only checked radio buttons.

```
var radio_buttons = $('.search-options input[type="radio"]:checked');
```

If you want to get checked radio button from collection in variable;

```
 var radio_buttons = $('.search-options input[type="radio"]');
 var radio_buttons_checked = radio_buttons.find(':checked');
```

For checked radio in container,

```
var radio_buttons = $('.search-options input[type="radio"]');
radio_buttons.each(function(){
     containerChecked = $(this).parent().find(':checked');
     alert(containerChecked.length);
});
```

Comment: That's not what I try to catch. The radio_buttons is a given variable, i can't change it. I want to search inside this variable.

Comment: Updated my answer, is it what you want?

Comment: No, this code will search inside the radio buttons and not in their container

Comment: For checked radio in container, radio_buttons.each(function(){containerChecked = $(this).parent().find(':checked')});

Comment: @Adil WTF is that? :) Simple `filter` does all the job, ain't you know?

Comment: I thought find will do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector, like this:

```
var radio_buttons = $('.search-options input[type="radio"]:checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var radio_buttons = $('.search-options input[type="radio"]:checked');
```